# запуск активити авторизации первым (не MainActivity) в Android приложении

Tags: activity

Всем привет. 
Кто нибудь может подсказать - в одном проекте пытаюсь первым запустить не main activity, а activity с вводом логина и пароля, но вот всё никак не получается, в манифесте уже указывал примерно следующее:

```
<activity
android:name=".ui.activities.LoginActivity"
android:label="@string/title_activity_login">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
</intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity android:name=".ui.activities.MainActivity">
</activity>
```

но вот никак....может еще где нужно что то прописать? вроде как только это надо было подправить в коде, чтобы первым было активити с авторизацией.
И самое интересное, создаю отдельный проект, потом в котором создаю активити с авторизацией, прописываю как выше написал и всё работает как надо (т.е. запускается активити авторизации первым).
Что может быть тут?

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос уже не актуален.
  Помогло создание нового проекта, в который перебросил всю логику из предыдущего. Т.к. уже писал, что проверил на чистом проекте те-же действия и всё запускалось как надо, т.е. начиная с активити авторизации. 
  А так до сих пор непонятно, что это было.